# private messages spring websocket

Tags: java, jquery, spring, websocket, stomp

I am learning spring websocket and I am stuck on how I can send messages to specific users using `@DestinationVariable("username")`
Here is my code

```
configuration
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketContextConfig extends AbstractSessionWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer<ExpiringSession> {

    @Override
    protected void configureStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws-cfg").withSockJS();

    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/queue/","/topic","/exchange/")
                .setRelayHost("localhost");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@MessageMapping("/chat.private.{username}")
    public void filterPrivateMessage(@Payload Message message, @DestinationVariable("username") String username, Principal principal) {

        this.simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(username, "/queue/chat.message", message);
    }
```

the client code

```
 var stomp = null;
            stomp = Stomp.over(new SockJS("/ws-cfg"));

           stomp.connect('guest', 'guest', function(frame) {

                stomp.subscribe("/user/queue/chat.message", function (frame) {
                    dysplayMessage(JSON.parse(frame.body));
                });

            })


            $("#sendMessage").click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var message = $('#text').val();
                var username="user@gmail.com";// i am lost in this part, i supose this must be the @DestinationVariable("username")
                destination = "/app/chat.private."+to;
                stomp.send(destination, {}, JSON.stringify({'text': message}));
                $('#text').val("");
            });
```

I am currently using websocket with spring security. How can I set the `@DestinationVariable("username")` on `stomp.send` method.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Spring WebSocket Chat sample which has what you are looking for: https://github.com/salmar/spring-websocket-chat

Comment: first of all, thank you its my pleasure to speak to you!!! i am studying basing on that project and your Deep dive into Spring WebSockets and From Zero to Hero with Spring WebSocket.  i dont know how to pass the username from stomp.send method to controller method. i thought the username referenced from @DestinationVariable  was from spring security but it is not. please, any sugestion?

Comment: @Sergi-Almar: I've read your code and it was very well organized, thank you for sharing. I have this question which may seem obvious, does create `@MessageMapping("/chat.private.{username}")` to send private messages uses different MQ topics for each user? For example, do 1000 online users need 1000 topics? What is the overhead of this number of topics? In the case of memory and process consumption.

Answer (score 0):

The Destination Variable gets populated from the payload you are sending. In your case, you have to include it like this

```
stomp.send(destination, {}, JSON.stringify({'text': message, 'username' : 'User1'}));
```

One more observation is you don't seem to be setting the UserDestinationPrefix. you need to set it up for both the MessageBrokerRegistry and SimpMessagingTemplate.